# Java - Fastest and Lowest usage way to read and store data

Tags: java, performance, memory, storage, lwjgl

I'm using java (LWJGL) to create sort of a game and I want to know the fastest way to read and store data in hard drive.
The game's world is some kind of a grid that represents 3D world and I need to store data about each cube of 1x1x1 size (or maybe lower in the future to get better resolution). I'm currently saving each record of cubes in a text file.
Each record stores data for 32x32x32 cube.

Right now, each record takes 625 KB in hard-disk memory, and reading the file takes 16 milliseconds (in my computer, without doing others things, just reading it).

I wonder if there is a better way to do it because I might use this method every 3 seconds (mostly won't, but sometimes will - need to keep the frame rate at 60).
A way to the same data so it will consume less memory and will be read faster.
The text files use only numbers, English letters, and some special characters (',' '(' ')' '{' '}' '-' '.' ':' and maybe some more).

I heard minecraft uses .mca files but I have no idea if they are better, or how to read them.

Comment: How is it stored? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing what you want would be to use serialization and object streams to store binary data to a file. Essentially, you would be storing your array object, or the object of a chunk (or whatever you call your subdivisions of terrain). This would achieve faster loading time since the JVM wouldn't have to re-construct every object upon loading.

The main advantage of using binary files is that you don't have to write any algorithm, or even iterate over the data when you wish to store it. As you mention that you would want to do frequent storing, this might be a good solution for you.

Here is an example to give you some pointers.

Assume:

```
class Chunk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Block[][][] chunkBlocks;
    // ... other code //
}
```

by adding the statement `implements Serializable` to you class definition, you signify that the class can be used to write and read objects from byte streams, thus allowing you to store them and read them from files. One more thing to note is the variable `serialVersionUID`. This is very important, because its what will tell the stream what class this object belongs to and if it can be casted to it. (note: that's a rough approximation but i will spare you the details for the sake of not being to verbose). Modern IDEs such as [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) will prompt you to add this variable to your class when you implement the Serializable interface. They will also give you the option of generating a unique ID for it. Ths is recomended to ensure there not be any conflicts.

finally, here is how you would go about storing an object:

```
/**
 * Object o         : the object you want to save
 * String filename  : the file path of where you want to save the object
 */
public static void save(Object o, String filename) {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oop = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        oop = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oop.writeObject(o);
        oop.flush();
        fos.flush();
        oop.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and loading one:

```
/**
 * @returns Object o : the object stored in the file @ filename
 * String filename   : the file path of where you want to save the object
 */
public static Object load(String filename) {

    FileInputStream in;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    Object o = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        o = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return o;

}
```

In the code above, I generalized the functions to take and return `java.lang.Object`, but you could change this to Chunk or whatever if you desire to have a function dedicated to a specific class.

You also mention the Minecraft file formats, but those are very application specific and are basically in a format that makes sense to it and it only. In addition to that, they aren't suited for frequent save as you would want to do it, they are better at background chunk unloading.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea that ' the JVM wouldn't have to re-construct every object upon loading.' That's exactly what de-serialization does. The explicit `close()`s of the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are redundant.

Comment: well one *could* argue that deserialization is not equal to construction because all of the properties are (hopefully) filled with predetermined values - the object instances themselves are new ones, yes but thats about it -- their *content* isnt _(given that we're dealing with primitive properties exclusively, that is)_. But i dont actually share that view .... im just sayan.

Comment: You're right, what i meant to say is that he would have to explicitly construct every object based on what he read from the file, which is a tedious process.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute fastest way to access a fixed-size file of the type you mention is via an NIO `MappedByeBuffer.`